# AJAX/PHP - populate different types of input fields with one ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, dropdown

I figured how to populate a text box via AJAX. I was also able to populate a dropdown select box from AJAX. But I can't seem to populate text boxes and select boxes at the same time from one AJAX call.

Here's a recreation of what I have:

```
<?php echo "
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascrpt">$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#test').change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"myurl",
                type:"POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {test: $(this).val()},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#team1').val(data["team1"]);
                    $('#team2').val(data["team2"]);
                    $('#team_member1').val(data["g1"]);
                }
            });
        });
});
</script>

<select name='test' id='test'>
  <option value='1'></option>
  <option value='2'></option>
  <option value='3'></option>
</select>

<input type='text' name='team1' id='team1' value='".$t1."'>
<select name='team_member1 id='team_member1'>
  <option value='".$output."'></option> <!--!!HELP HERE!!-->
</select>

<input type='text' name='team2' id='team2' value='".$t2."'>
```

myurl.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","local");
$output='';

$sql = "SELECT name FROM team WHERE id='".$_POST["test"]."'";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $output .= '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}


$t1='Boston Falcons';
$t2='Human Resources';

$response = array(
    "team1" => $t1,
    "team2" => $t2,
    "g1"=>$output, <---mysql resultset for dropdown not working
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Upon changing `#test`,AJAX is able to pre populate `#team1` and `#team2`  text fields with their respective strings from `myurl.php`.

However, it doesnt pre populate `#team_member1` with a list of options `$output` (mysql result set) though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a quoting problem here. Your entire string si within double quotes so you need to `escape` and double quotes within that string

Comment: besides the quoting error you have a comma to much after $output in your ouput arrayand you should read up on prepared statements in mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out in the AJAX success, I need to return `$('#team_member1').html(data["g1"]);`

instead of 
`$('#team_member1').val(data["g1"]);`